# Warning - 'java.lang.Override' is deprecated (onCreate method)

Tags: android, deprecated

I just created a new project in Android Studio Version 3.1.3 (June 4, 2018)

[image]

> App Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.anonymous.hotvideos"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: For reference, [it's not](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Override). Probably a cache issue. Try invalidating the caches and restarting the IDE

Comment: @Zoe Still, it's showing same warning :(

Answer (score 0):

search in your computer to find "annotations.xml".
then delete there:

```
<item name='java.lang.Override'>
<annotation name='java.lang.Deprecated' />
```